# SQL Server - show output into columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to build a report from user licenses from an application. One user can have several licenses as shown below:

```
user_name   license name
---------   -------------------------
toreilly    GWM Generation Moneypoint
toreilly    GWM Generation Aghada
toreilly    GWM Generation Ardnacrusha
toreilly    GWM Asset Development
toreilly    GWM Generation Erne
toreilly    GWM Generation Dublin Bay Power
toreilly    GWM Generation Lough Ree Power
toreilly    GWM Generation Lee
```

What I'm trying to do is show the output in one row only and the several license names into several columns like this:

```
user_name       license name license name
--------------- --------------------------  ---------------------   
toreilly    GWM Generation Moneypoint   GWM Generation Aghada
```

Can you help me on this?

Thanks, Bruno

Comment: Wouldn't two columns be sufficient? One with the user_name and one with a comma delimited list of the license names?

Comment: Look into pivot https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but to use PIVOT don't you need an aggregate function? I just want the output. The problem about comma delimited list is because this is going to be automated using an SSIS package that extracts the data into excel but because a user can have many licenses it truncates the result set in excel.

Answer (score 0):

With MySql f.e you could simply use:

```
SELECT user_name group_concat(license) FROM licenses GROUP BY user_name
```

This would return rows with the username and a coma separated list of licenses.

MSQL doesn't have the group_concat function, so you'd need to use something like this:

```
SELECT user_name, licenses=STUFF(
  (SELECT ','+licence FROM licenses WHERE user_name=X.user_name FOR XMLPATH('')) , 1 , 1 , '' )
FROM licenses X
GROUP BY user_name
```

*untested and orientated on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)*

**edit:** This isn't exactly what you described, as the licenses are now in one column, but the nearest i could think of.

Comment: The problem is I'm avoiding comma separated list because this is going to be automated using an SSIS package that extracts  the data into excel but because a user can have many licenses it truncates the result set in excel.